# JPasswordField and KeyListener

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, jpasswordfield

Can anyone help me with this code as I am a newbie in Java. I found this code on the web and I want to understand what it does?

```
pass = new JPasswordField(10);
    pass.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyChar()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                    OKButton.doClick();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                //Do Nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                //Do Nothing
            }

    });
```

As I understand it creates a text where everything I type is not visible, and I see bullets instead. Whats the purpose of the KeyListener? To identify the letters pressed?

Comment: This is a terrible example to learn from. You should NOT be using a KeyListener for this. If you want to listen for the Enter key then you should add an ActionListener to the text field. You can add the same ActionListener to the button and the text field.

Comment: not, never, very bad, agreed with @camickr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `if(e.getKeyChar()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)` checks whether the `Key pressed` is `ENTER` key or not.

If user pressed `ENTER KEY` the java code automatically presses `OK Button`.

For further understanding take a look at [How to Write a Key Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html).

Answer (score 1):

This code describes a field in which the user would put in a password. The point of the implementation of the KeyListener interface is to check if the user has pressed the Enter key on their keyboard. If the user does, the program clicks the OK button for him.

More on KeyListener: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html